# C# equivalent to Java's Thread.setDaemon?

Tags: c#, java, .net, multithreading, daemon

How do I set a thread to a daemon thread in C#?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/should-i-ask-a-question-i-know-the-answer-to

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Though you have already answered your **own** question, I would still like to elaborate more on it.

In C# .NET, unlike in Java

```
   C# Background threads ~ Java Daemon threads  
   C# Foreground threads ~ Java User threads
```

By default, threads you create explicitly are `foreground` threads.

"Background threads are identical to foreground threads, except that background threads do not prevent a process from terminating."
([reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.thread.isbackground%28v=vs.110%29.aspx))

You can make a thread Daemon by

```
thread.IsBackground = true;
```

Comment: excellent, thanks! :) and re: answering my own question, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/should-i-ask-a-question-i-know-the-answer-to

Answer (score 11):

Like this:

```
myThread.IsBackground = true;
```